# Send additional authorization details to Keycloak PAR endpoint

Tags: keycloak

I am new to Keycloak and Authorization Servers. I have a requirement to include a dynamic custom JSON body in the `access_token` when it is issued using Keycloak. I would appreciate guidance on how to achieve this by following the steps outlined below.

1. I have set up a Keycloak realm called `"realm-test"` and created a client named `"postman"`. Additionally, I created a Mapper User Attribute called additional_json, which is crucial for achieving my goal (more details below).
2. To initiate the token issuance process, I make a POST request to the PAR (Pushed Authorization Requests) endpoint:

```
POST https://my.domain.com:8443/auth/realms/realm-test/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request
```

In the request, I include the following parameters:

- client_id: postman
- client_secret: generated by Keycloak
- response_type: code
- **additional_json**: This is a dynamic JSON body that I want to include in the resulting access_token. As an example, let's say I want to include the following JSON:

```
{
  "test": "something"
}
```

**This is a variable and can't be a constant added in Keycloak client or realm configuration.**

3. The response from the PAR endpoint:

```
{
    "request_uri": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:request_uri:4a64c66c-4d96-4d49-bf9b-852b1ae71d33",
    "expires_in": 60
}
```

4. Next, I call the authorize endpoint to obtain the authorization code:

```
GET https://my.domain.com:8443/auth/realms/realm-test/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=postman&request_uri=urn:ietf:params:oauth:request_uri:4a64c66c-4d96-4d49-bf9b-852b1ae71d33
```

5. I successfully receive the authorization code, allowing me to proceed to the next step.
6. Finally, I make a request to the token endpoint to obtain the `access_token`. However, despite following these steps, the `additional_json` parameter is not included in the resulting token. I have attempted to use a `Mapper User Attribute`, but it only enables me to add hardcoded claims.

Ideally, I would like the resulting JWT token to contain the additional JSON, for example:

```
{
  "exp": 1687197451,
  "iat": 1687197151,
  "auth_time": 1687197026,
  ...
  "test": "something",
  ...
}
```

Can someone please guide me on how to make this work with Keycloak?

**UPDATE**

I was able to pick the request parameter and add to the JWT token but only if I send it directly to the "/protocol/openid-connect/token" endpoint (step 6 above). I did it using a Script Mapper, as per below code:

```
var req = keycloakSession.getContext().getContextObject(Java.type("org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpRequest").class);
token.setOtherClaims("test", req.getDecodedFormParameters().getFirst("test"));
```

The problem is that I need to pass this request parameter to the PAR and have it stored somehow to be added in the token afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

1. first goto **Clients** -> click on the **ClientID** of your application that you want to create attribute
2. Go to **ClientScopes** of the menu tab of your Client App
3. click on the **cliendID-dedicated** scope
4. Click on th add mapper ->select **By configuration**  ,select ***User Attribute*** and add the following namespaces.
   [image]
5. go to **Users**->click on the user you want to create attribute , Add attribute as :**test :something**
   [image]
6. go to **Role mapping** of the user  and select the role of that user of that  **client app** (Foe ex: here user should be a a user of an client app )
7. Now test it you can see the json code in your access token.
   [image]

Comment: That does not work, nothing changed in the generated token and I followed all the steps. I was reading about client scopes and it seems we can only add scopes with fixed value, not dynamic (with value provided in the PAR request) as I need. Note that additional_json can be anything, it is not fixed. The value I provided was only an example.

Comment: @Ventrue I tested and got the result , Please follow the steps now , Incase any doubts post it here

Comment: Sorry but you are missing the most important point here: I can't have a constant value for the JSON. It must be a variable provided by the client via "additional_json" request parameter to the PAR endpoint. It can be anything, not a fixed value. The "test: something" was just an example.